# how do i know this without using calculator :$\sqrt{(9999²+19999)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I'm sorry to ask this question , I would like to know the value of this :$\sqrt{(9999²+19999)}$ without using calculator ?

Note :I have used digit root theory but it's not work ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Hint: $19999=2\cdot 9999+1$.

Comment: thank you ,Then sorry for my question, i didn't get attention

Comment: Hint: $9999=10^4-1$.

Answer (score 6):

$\sqrt{9999^2+19999}=\sqrt{9999^2+(10000-9999)(10000+9999)}=\sqrt{9999^2+(10000^2-9999^2)}=\sqrt{10000^2}=10000$